# query related to String constant pool

Tags: java, string, immutability

PFB the piece of code I'm trying to understand.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "dexter7";
    String s2 = "dexter" + "7";

    System.out.println(s1==s2); //line 1 - Output is true

    String s3 = "dexter" + s1.length();

    System.out.println(s1==s3); //line 2 - Output is false

}
```

As per the concept of string constant pool, if there exists a String value in the constant pool, it will be reused instead of creating a new String unless the "new" keyword is in picture.

So why does this behavior change in the above snippet considering the output from line 1 & line 2 as marked in the above snippet.

Can anyone help me in understanding this.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `s1.length()` is not a constant expression.

Comment: There are a lot of duplicates for this question on SO. Do search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1.length()` is evaluated not at compile time but at runtime so

```
String s3 = "dexter" + s1.length();
```

will be compiled into

```
String s3 = new StringBuilder("dexter").append(s1.length()).toString();
```

and `toString` will use `new String(...)` internally to create `s3` so it will not come from strings pool.

---

On the other hand

```
String s2 = "dexter" + "7";
```

are concatenated by compiler and compiled into

```
String s2 = "dexter7";
```

so `s2` is the same string literal as `s1`.